# Animation for a period

Tags: jquery

I Asked this question before yesterday but it was closed because -maybe- of my bad english . so i will try to explain the best that I can . I have a div with background image , the png background is a set of images (contain many images and by changing css background position I can choose which image to appear in the div - I think it's a popular usage) .
The problem is that I want to do an animation to do this:

```
$('div').css('background', "url('back.png') 0 -750px");
```

then :

```
$('div').css('background', "url('back.png') 0 -100px");
```

that's moving background up and down ,I want to do that for 4 sec ,I hope you understand 
I tried delay(); setTimeout(); but they keep doing that forever !!

***Update:***  to explain more imagine a Gif image that flash for 4sec then stop !!

Comment: Do you want to move the background, wait for 4 seconds, move it again, and so on? Also, don't apologise for bad English; try getting me to speak some Spanish!

Comment: no i want to keep moving the background for 4sec then stop the animation like a flash!!

Comment: Maybe this will help you: http://www.spritely.net/

Comment: @Felix maybe "Making a sprite play for a fixed number of frames" is the key i will try thx !!

Comment: Not sure if that's it. But you can setup the animation and start and stop it at your will.

Comment: Problem!! spritely do not allow defining frames , it calculate the frame size automatically using size of container and number of frames .. that's a problem because my backgroung contain some images that shouldn't appear !!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this tutorial, it may help point you in the right direction:

http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/jquery-bg-image-animations

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thx , but that's not the point !! I Already read this but doesn't help .. thx a lot anyway !!

Answer (score 0):

Possibly something like this should work (didn't test it though):

```
$('#div').animate({
  background: 'url("back.png") 0 -100px'
  }, 4000, function() {
  // What to do when the animation is done
});
```

Take a look at http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: That's will do the animation for one time .. I want to keep moving the background up and down for 4sec , just like a Gif image that stop after 4sec !!